# Git add . vs git add -A

Tags: git, git-add

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre usar `git add .` y `git add -A`?

Estuve buscando una diferencia clara pero no la encuentro.

Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Respuesta corta:**
git add -A es igual a git add. + git add -u

**Explicación:**
Cuando hace un "git add.", Agrega todos los archivos (existentes, modificados y nuevos) al área de preparación pero no elimina los archivos que se han eliminado del disco.

"git add -u" solo agrega los archivos rastreados actualmente (que se han modificado) al área de preparación y también verifica si se han eliminado (en caso afirmativo, se eliminan del área de preparación). Esto significa que no presenta nuevos archivos.

Hacer "git add -A" realiza estos dos pasos, es decir, organiza todo el directorio tal como está.

**Resumen:**
git add -A: pone en escena todo
git add -u: solo etapas archivos modificados
git add. : Organiza todo, sin archivos eliminados

Dejo aquí un enlace a la [documentación](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-add.html)

PD: esto es una traducción de la respuesta a una pregunta similar en la versión en inglés de SO que se encuentra en el siguiente enlace: [What's the difference between "git add -u" and "git add -A"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15011311/whats-the-difference-between-git-add-u-and-git-add-a)